# How can I check and verify code before committing in Android Studio?

Tags: android, optimization, plugins, lint

In Android Studio, I check the code by `Analyze`->`Inspect code` before committing the code. That is so weird and time-consuming to check it every day and also to check it for different computers. What I want is, I set lint configuration and it will check it automatically while committing the code. Do anyone has configured their Android Studio in this way? How can I do it? Is there any plugin for that? I want to do it because I have read good code quality is equal to good handwriting.

Comment: Have you read [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint.html) on how to configure a custom lint checker?

Comment: @MatPag I think the OP is about running lint automatically when committing, not creating a custom lint checker

Comment: AS is asking me out of the box if i really want to commit when there is warning or error in the code or if want to review them.

Comment: AS gives you a dialog displaying the warning it founds (lint checker included) before committing the code

Comment: Maybe it will be better to deploy [CI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration)/[CD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_delivery) service like [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/) or [TeamCity](https://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) and make such checks run on a regular basis, e.g. every day or upon push to development branch.

Answer (score 1):

How are you committing your changes?  If you use the Commit Changes from the VCS menu (or equivalent keystroke) then there is a whole load of options you can select to be done before the commit, including reformat code, optimize imports, and perform code analysis.